# How to force a href link to be absolute?

Tags: javascript, android, html, url, href

So, I have an hybrid webapp in android and I want to redirect my users to one of my Google Forms. The code looks like this:

```
<a href="https://goo(.)gl/forms/..." target="_blank">Text</a>
```

But whenever I click on the link, I get the following error:

```
Application Error
net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND (file:///android_asset/www/%22https://goo(.)gl/forms/...%22)
```

Somehow the link is relative to the root of my app, and I want it to be absolute.

Thank you in advance for your help.

PS: I put brackets in the goo(.)gl URL because otherwise I wasn't allowed to publish the URL

Comment: Probably not the best solution, but `onclick='window.open(url)'` works.

Answer (score -1):

A link gets automatically absolute when we use http, https in the begining.
I don't know why you are getting this error. Maybe You should try it in pc.

Comment: NO, a link with only `www` at the beginning is not considered as absolute ; `www` is not a standard nor a protocol, it's just a sub-domain name. Some websites don't have any sub-domain (stackoverflow) or use `www2` or any other identifier.